# incompatible pointer types passing short * to short *(*)[ ]

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, implicit-conversion

Certainly, I did something wrong here, but looking at this I can't figure out why I am receiving these warnings:

```
warning: incompatible pointer types passing '__int16_t *' (aka 'short *') to parameter of type '__int16_t *(*)[4]' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        hammingDistance2d(ptr0, ptr1);
```

in my small code segment:

```
void hammingDistance2d(__int16_t *src0[N][N],
                       __int16_t *src1[N][N]){
    int i, j;
    __uint16_t Hdis[N][N] = {0};

    for (i=0 ; i<N; i++){
        for (j=0; j<N; j++){
            __uint16_t z = *src0[i][j] ^ *src1[i][j];
            while (z > 0)
            {
                Hdis[i][j] += z & 1;
                z >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }
int main(){

    __int16_t src0[N][N] = {  { 1, 1, 1, 1},
                              { 2, 2, 2, 2},
                              { 3, 3, 3, 3},
                              { 4, 4, 4, 4} };
    __int16_t src1[N][N] = {  { 1, 1, 1, 1},
                              { 2, 2, 2, 2},
                              { 5, 5, 5, 5}, // different row
                              { 4, 4, 4, 4} };
    __int16_t *ptr0 =  &src0[0][0];
    __int16_t *ptr1 =  &src1[0][0];

    hammingDistance2d(ptr0, ptr1);
    return 0;
}
```

and I'd like to use keep the use of intermediate pointers to the arrays.

Comment: Why are you using `__int16_t` (which is a system type; the double-underscore prefix is reserved for the implementation) instead of `int16_t` (which is the usable version of the type name)?

Comment: `*src0[N][N]` is a 2D array of pointers, to which you pass the address of one element of a 2D array of integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These variables

```
__int16_t *ptr0 =  &src0[0][0];
__int16_t *ptr1 =  &src1[0][0];
```

are explicitly declared as having the type `__int16_t *`.

But the corresponding function parameters

```
void hammingDistance2d(__int16_t *src0[N][N],
                       __int16_t *src1[N][N]){
```

in fact has the type `__int16_t * ( * )[N]`.

There is no implicit conversion from the first type to the second. So the compiler issues an error.

It seems what you mean is the following

```c
void hammingDistance2d(__int16_t src0[N][N],
                       __int16_t src1[N][N]){
    int i, j;
    __uint16_t Hdis[N][N] = {0};

    for (i=0 ; i<N; i++){
        for (j=0; j<N; j++){
            __uint16_t z = src0[i][j] ^ src1[i][j];
            while (z > 0)
            {
                Hdis[i][j] += z & 1;
                z >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a function call can look like

```
hammingDistance2d( src0, src1 );
```

If you want to declare intermediate pointers used as the function arguments then you should write

```
__int16_t ( *ptr0 )[N] =  src0;
__int16_t ( *ptr1 )[N] =  src1;
```

and call the function like

```
hammingDistance2d( ptr0, ptr1 );
```

Comment: Thanks @Vlad. If I wanted to use pointers here, what would have been the correct form then?

Comment: @Amir Do you mean to use pointers within the function instead of the subscript operator?

Comment: thanks @Vlad, I guess there was my issue and I thought just like a 1d array for which &src[0] has the starting address, a &src[0][0] must have been having the same thing for a 2d.

Comment: @Amir The values of addresses can coincide but the types of expressions are different. And you may not to apply two subscript operators to a pointer of the type  __int16_t *

Answer (score 2):

You're passing a 2D array of `__int16`, but your function is expecting a pointer to `__int16_t`.

Fix the function definition to work with what you're sending it.

```
void hammingDistance2d(__int16_t src0[N][N],
                       __int16_t src1[N][N]){
    int i, j;
    __uint16_t Hdis[N][N] = {0};

    for (i=0 ; i<N; i++){
        for (j=0; j<N; j++){
            __uint16_t z = src0[i][j] ^ src1[i][j];
            while (z > 0)
            {
                Hdis[i][j] += z & 1;
                z >>= 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

And call it as:

```
hammingDistance2d(src0, src1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function is expecting:

```
__int16_t *src0[N][N]
```

Which has type (as the compiler suggests) `__int16_t *(*)[4]`, or, in English: pointer to [pointer to [array of 4 `__int16_t`]] (notice the square brackets I am using for emphasis).

What you have here:

```
__int16_t src0[N][N] = {  { 1, 1, 1, 1},
                          { 2, 2, 2, 2},
                          { 3, 3, 3, 3},
                          { 4, 4, 4, 4} };
```

Is of type `__int16_t (*)[4]`, that is: pointer to [array of 4 `__int16_t`].

You probably meant to declare:

```
hammingDistance2d(__int16_t src0[N][N], __int16_t src1[N][N]) {
    // ...
}
```

Which is the same as:

```
hammingDistance2d(__int16_t (*src0)[N], __int16_t (*src1)[N]) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that in such case you *don't* have to dereference `src0[i][j]` using the `*` operator.